# Change database instance when deploying to another project in MicroStrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I'm attempting to figure out the best way to deploy packages / duplicate projects etc. in MicroStrategy.

I have two seperate MSTR instances set up, with the current setup of my environment looks a little something like this:

- MSTR A instance, 1 project (production) >> queries **production** data warehouse
- MSTR B instance, 2 projects (test and development) >> queries **development** data warehouse

Everything is brand new, so in the first instance, I would like to follow best practice when deploying all the way to production, so this would mean:

- Develop artifacts in MSTR B instance (development project)
- Duplicate project to MSTR B instance (test project)
- Allow business users to test
- Duplicate projecct to MSTR A instance (production project)

This seems fairly straight forward, but this is my main problem:

When deploying from MSTR B instance (development project) to MSTR B instance (test project), MSTR Object Manager attempts to move the database instance (querying the **development** data warehouse) as well. This is because tables are dependant on that particular database instance. That makes total sense, except I want MSTR to query tables from our production data warehouse after deploying to another environment.

**So during the project / object manager deployment process between projects, is there a way I can change the connection to the production data warehouse?**

Obviously confirming the underlying data structure in the data warehouses would be like for like.

Is there a better way of doing this? What deployment processes do people follow? Or does everyone just point MSTR prod/test/dev instances to the same production sources?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I use the object manager to deploy releases from the test to the prod environment. I create a package with contains all release objects. Test and Prod environments have different source connections. You config this connection separately, but they have the same ID.